# How to dynamically add views in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a template View called PageShell that allows me to define a page structure for all the pages in my app. When a new page presenter is created it will create a PageShell view and set the menu and main views.

PageShell.ui.xml

```
<ui:style>
.pageMenuDiv {
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.pageMainDiv {
    height:100%;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
.pageContainer {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</ui:style>

    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="pageContainer">
    <div id="pageMenuDiv" class="{style.pageMenuDiv}"/>
    <div id="pageMainDiv" class="{style.pageMainDiv}"/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I run into problems when trying to dynamically add the views to the 2 DIVs above by using either add(menuView, "pageMenuDiv") or addAndReplaceElement (no errors but the newly inserted views do not show up).

However, it works fine if instead of DIVs I use:

```
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.pageContainer}" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g:SimplePanel ui:field="pageMenuContainer" styleName="{style.pageMenuDiv}"/>
    <g:SimplePanel ui:field="pageMainContainer" styleName="{style.pageMainDiv}"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

What is the right approach to achieve this?
Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

A think that you have to give two different names to divs for example

```
<div id="pageMenuDiv1" class="{style.pageMenuDiv}"/>
<div id="pageMainDiv2" class="{style.pageMainDiv}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Shilaghae, they already have different ids: pageMenuDiv & pageMainDiv.